# Take photo programmatically using a timer

Tags: iphone, objective-c, timer, photo

I'm looking for a method to make photo in Objective-C from code and an image displayer using a timer.

I mean: I would like an interface similar to the standard photo app, but the photo must not be took after pressing a button, but the button must start a timer (from the timer I will check for other values).

Let's make an example:

- I press the button
- The timer starts
- After 1-2 seconds of checking values, the photo gets took
- The photo gets saved on the Photo Library automatically.
- The application is ready to make other photos

But I don't have idea on how to begin that. I saw examples of code which called the Photo Application, but nothing which makes that from code, although I see many apps do that. When the photo gets took, it should be simply saved.

How can I do that?

Comment: So basically you want to implement a photo app with a countdown function?

Comment: I'd like to check the values to make a verify, if the result is true, the photo gets took, if not, the timer rebegins, obviously it would include a Cancel button. Anyway I don't think this internal code is important for you helping me.

Comment: I'm reading a manual and I'm making some trying from 2-3 weeks, but I'm not expert with these events and frameworks.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`UIImagePickerController`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html) to show the default camera GUI.

```
UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
picker.showsCameraControls = NO;
```

You can hide the default camera controls by setting `showsCameraControls` to `NO`. Then you can define your own controls by creating a `UIView`, adding your controls and setting `cameraOverlayView` to that view.

```
UIView *cameraControlsView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:controlsFrame];
UIButton *captureButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:buttonFrame];
[captureButton setTitle:@"Capture" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[captureButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:)        
        forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[cameraControlsView addSubview:captureButton];
picker.cameraOverlayView = cameraControlsView;
```

When the user taps your custom capture `UIButton`, you can start the timer. When the timer fires, you do the verifications and use the `takePicture` method to capture an image.

```
- (void)buttonPressed:(id)sender {
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:3.0f target:self 
     selector:@selector(timerFired:) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
}

- (void)timerFired:(NSTimer *)timer {
    if (whateverIsOk) {
        [self.picker takePicture];
    )
}
```

Comment: Man, thanks for this helping but I'm having some difficulties to apply it, there's a warning, the timer is never used and when I press the button nothing happens.

Comment: What warning? Did you succeed in creating the GUI and the button? It's not a copy-paste solution, I just typed this out in here, without checking for possible errors.

Comment: I created the GUI and the button, but when I press it nothing happens, and the warning is "Unused variable timer", on your event - (void)timerFired:(NSTimer *)timer

Comment: My mistake, you don't need to save it into a variable. Are you sure the timer does nothing? Is `timerFired:` executed?

Comment: I tried to execute only [self.picker takePicture]; to evit that issue, but no clue, it doesn't work.

Code of .m file
http://pastebin.com/qLhyu0Wj

Code of .h file http://pastebin.com/d1T1FAGR

Comment: You never set `self.picker`. You have to do that after setting up the picker.

Answer (score 0):

There is a method in the UIImagePickerController class to take picture programatically

```
-(void)takePicure
```

to save the image to the photo Library, you have two options

1. using ALAssetLibrary

   `ALAssetsLibrary *al = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
   [al writeImageDataToSavedPhotosAlbum:user.photo.image metadata:nil completionBlock:^(NSURL *assetURL, NSError *error) { }];`
2. `void UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(UIImage *image, 
                 id completionTarget, SEL completionSelector, void *contextInfo);`

Comment: I think `takePicture` already saves to the Photo Library, doesn't it?

Comment: I don't think so. I will check